# Using MSDeploy to install windows services from package

Tags: windows-services, msdeploy

I've read where it's possible to utilize MSDeploy to install windows services or even performance counters on a remote machine.  I see how this can be accomplished using the MSDeploy "sync" from a source directory to a destination directory.  Is there some way of actually having the source be the binaries contained within the .zip file itself so the .zip can be copied onto the remote machine and then execute msdeploy?  If so, how is the source directory referenced from within the manifest.xml?  There doesn't seem to be a large amount of documentation on MSDeploy aside from traditional web site and database deployment.  Any helpful links would be appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to know an answer to this, we are currently using a dirPath package to deploy windowsservices, and install them by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSDeploy to install windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055617/msdeploy-to-install-windows-service)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MSDeploy` to call `installutil` in order to install the service, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055617/msdeploy-to-install-windows-service).